When needing to count likes, views, etc per post whats the better approach?
I’m making an app using django where users can make posts. To add likes and views which can be counted and sent to be displayed on frontend i’m thinking of two approaches.

is to use a reverse foreign-key relation between post’s model and likes model to dynamically count the instances of the likes model each each time. So create/delete instances of like model to represent like/unlike

is to use a integer field model to store the counts in the database.

use many-to-many field where number if likes for a post is determined my NO. Of user instances associated with post.likes


Which approach does instagram use? Which approach would be the ultimate choice? Considering keeping costs low while maintaining scalability possibilities. Thanks

What is the difference between the first and the last one?

The 1st uses foreign keys from like model to post model and can be two way. The 3rd one uses built in many-to-many field.

I would suggest a combination of approaches.
First, I think counting likes when displaying a post would perform terribly. You would have the problem that most people on your website will view your most popular content. (By definition!) However, the most popular content will also be liked more often, which increases the CPU time needed to render that page. This means that the amount of work your webserver needs to do will go up as the square of the number of people who want to view it. That gets out of hand quickly. Therefore, I think you have to store a like count.
However, if you were to just store a like count, you will have the same problem that Reddit, StackOverflow, and others have, which is that there are groups of bots/users who will vote for each other's content. If you have a list of likes, and you can track them back to users, you can look for collusion. If all you have is the number of likes, this is impossible to fix after the fact.
So, you need to store the same data (likes and like counts) in multiple different ways. This means that you should also have a strategy to reconcile conflicting data. Some possible ideas:

Every time someone likes a post, don't just increase the like counter by 1. Add the like to the database, do a count of the associated likes, and write that to the like count.
When you add a like to a post, increment the like counter by 1. Have a batch job which runs once a day, and re-calculates the like count for each post.
Some more sophisticated strategy.

I think approaches one and three are very similar in terms of the database structure. Approach three implicitly creates a link table which has a very similar structure to a model which has a foreign key to both post and user. If you want to add metadata to the like, it is slightly more work to add that to a ManyToMany through table than a dedicated model. I think either 1 or 3 is OK, though.

A custom through table for the many to many should be used IMO, that will allow you to add metadata like the timestamp of the like which will be useful to increase efficiency of the batch job. As an aside Stack Overflow also denormalizes post scores this way (See comment from a former staff)

Would the many to many not dynamically count the likes each time it’s viewed by a user? This gives the same issue as counting instances of like model in foreign key method. Should i have a separate integer counter where the each new instance (foreign key) or (many to many) the counted is updated by 1. So each new like recounts the all the likes dynamically to make sure the counter is correct. And when someone is viewing the post the total likes is retrieved from the stored counter instead of dynamically recounting each view? What do you guys think?

@Awm Right, this is the combination of approaches I discuss in my answer.
